# Combined pressure of two ideal gases with the same temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I want to calculate the combined pressure of two ideal gases $A$ and $B$ with pressure, temperature, particle number, entropy and volume $p_A$, $p_B$, $T_A$, $T_B$, $N_A$, $N_B$, $S_A$, $S_B$, $V_A$, $V_B$. I want to calculate it with the help of Maxwell equations. Particularly
$$
-p=\frac{\partial U}{\partial V} \quad \text{and} \quad T=\frac{\partial U}{\partial S} \quad \text{where $U=U(S,V,N)$}
$$
So the first thing is to express the internal energy as a function of $S,V,N$.
$$
U=\frac{3}{2}Nk_BT=\frac{3}{2}Nk_B\bigg(\frac{N}{V}\bigg)^{2/3}e^{\frac{\frac{S}{N}-\sigma}{k_B}\frac{2}{3}}
$$
the temperature can be replaced by transposing the entropy of the ideal gas $S=Nk_B\bigg(ln\big(\frac{V}{N}\big)+\frac{3}{2}ln(T)\bigg)+N\sigma$ where $\sigma=k_B\bigg(ln\big(\frac{(2\pi mk_B)3/2}{h^3}\big)+\frac{5}{2}\bigg)$ 
First the pressure: I assume that I combine two systems that have equal Temperature $T_A=T_B=T$ but not necessarily the the same Volume, Entropy or Particle number.
The pressure of the combined system can be expressed as
$$
-p_{AB}=\frac{\partial U(S_{AB},V_{AB},N_{AB})}{\partial V_{AB}} 
$$
with 
$S_{AB}=S_A+S_B$,
 $V_{AB}=V_A+V_B$,
 $N_{AB}=N_A+N_B$
In the following calculation I will suppress the $AB$ index. Calculating this one gets
$$
-p_{AB}=\frac{3}{2}Nk_B\big(-\frac{2}{3}\big)\frac{N^{2/3}}{V^{5/3}}e^{\frac{\frac{S}{N}-\sigma}{k_B}\frac{2}{3}}=-\frac{N}{V}k_B\big(\frac{N}{V}\big)^{2/3}e^{\frac{\frac{S}{N}-\sigma}{k_B}\frac{2}{3}}=-\frac{N}{V}k_BT=-\frac{N_A+N_B}{V_A+V_B}k_BT_{AB}
$$
Discussion:
 in the case of $p_A=p_B$, because $p=\frac{N}{V}k_BT$ and they have the same temperature $T_A=T_B$, it follows that $\frac{N_A}{V_A}=\frac{N_B}{V_B}$. So $N_A=c\cdot N_B$ and $V_A=c\cdot V_B$. Inserting this into the above equation for the pressure of the combined system yields.
$$
p_{AB}=\frac{N_A+cN_A}{V_A+cV_A}k_BT=\frac{N_A(1+c)}{V_A(1+c)}k_BT=\frac{N_A}{V_A}k_BT=p_A
$$
The same can be done with system $B$ to get $p_{AB}=p_B$. Which proofs that the pressure is an internal variable.
Do you agree with my calculations? I came up with that by my own train of thought and would like to hear the opinion of others from this. Because if my calculations were correct
$$
p_{AB}=\frac{N_A+N_B}{V_A+V_B}k_BT
$$
would be a formula for the new pressure when combining/connecting two systems with the same temperature. Maybe there is someone that has more experience in this field and can verify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two comments...

(a) Your first two equations are not Maxwell relations (but may be used to obtain the Maxwell relation $-\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial S} \right)_V=\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V} \right)_S$ ).

(b) Your final equation is correct if the container volume after the gases are combined is $(V_A+V_B)$. This equation follows immediately from *Dalton's law of partial pressures*, which is easily justified from elementary kinetic theory.